# Ist Geschlechtgerechtigkeit bei substantivierten Adjektiven schlicht Geschmackssache?

Tags: adjective, gender, gender-neutrality

In der [taz](http://taz.de/Sterben-im-sozialen-Netzwerk/!154879/) habe ich folgenden Abschnitt gefunden:

> Bisher gab es im Todesfall auf dem Account **des** oder **der** Verstorbenen einen Hinweis auf den Tod des Users, niemand konnte mehr auf das Profil zugreifen.

Wäre *der* nicht da, würde man was anderes verstehen? (etwa: dass der User männlich war).

Comment: Willst Du das wirklich so fragen? Welche Art von Antwort, die über eine Meinung hinausgeht, erwartest Du?

Comment: In der taz schon... ^_^

Comment: Ja gut, ich wüsste nicht, wieso es über eine Meinung hinausginge. Gibt's etwa keine Regel? Es ist nicht das gleiche wie "Studenten und Studentinnen", der Nomen da ist was anderes, als ob *Verstorben* eher schon Geschlechtsneutral wäre.

Comment: Es gibt die männliche Form "der Verstorbene" und die weibliche "die Verstorbene". Was die Verwendung der männlichen Form als allgmeine angeht, sind wir dann wieder bei den alten Fragen.

Comment: Das ist eine Diskussion, für die man ein ganz eigenes Forum machen kann. Ich vote klar "close". Nein, es gibt keine Regel. Man würde es auch ohne "der" verstehen. Nebenbei bemerkt, gendered die Taz im gleichen Satz bei "User" nicht. Über epic fail, Taz!

Comment: @Emanuel Ich hätte jetzt gesagt, dass keine verweiblichte Form von User gibt, aber der Duden scheint doch wirklich sowohl `User` als auch `Userin` zu kennen.

Comment: @Toscho... da kannman halt dann drüber diskutieren, warum es "der" User ist, und nicht das neutrale "das" User. Und durch das erste Gendern in dem Satz impliziert die Taz, dass "der" per se männlich ist. Ohne das erste, würde man das zweite vielleicht garnicht merken :)

Comment: Haha, wie viele falsche Ansichten! Nein, @Emanuel, man kann nicht "das User" sagen, wie man auch nicht "das Fußgänger" sagen kann. Und die Vergangenheitsform eines Fremdworts (gendern) wird nach deutscher Grammatik gebildet, also "es wurde gegendert" (wie gerendert).

Comment: Die Frage ist überhaupt nicht meinungsbasiert sondern lässt sich objektiv beurteilen. Es handelt sich um das bekannte Phänomen des gewollten Sprechens, wo am Sprachzentrum vorbei der Sprache eine Aufgabe aufgezwungen werden soll - siehe dazu http://www.belleslettres.eu/artikel/genus-gendersprech.php , ein Sprachwissenschaftler der wie ich der Meinung ist, dass es unwissenschaftlich ist, zu behaupten es sei eine Meinungsfrage.

Comment: vielleicht meinen die mit "der" einfach den Plural

Comment: @falkb ich glabe nicht, denn normalerweise teilt man kein FB-Konto mit jemandem (der Artikel geht eben darum, dass der *oder die* Verstorbene sein oder ihr Konto jmdm vertrauen kann, falls er oder sie stirtb) :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Im Allgemeinen ist eine derart besondere Betonung der sprachlichen Gleichbehandlung von Frauen und Männern nicht erforderlich.

Die objektiv strengsten Anforderungen an die sprachliche Gleichbehandlung von Frauen und Männern gelten sicherlich bei der sprachlichen Gestaltung von Gesetzen und Rechtsverordnungen. Und selbst in dem vom deutschen Bundesministerium der Justiz herausgegebenen *Handbuch der Rechtsförmlichkeit* <sub><sup>(3. Auflage 2008; Empfehlungen des Bundesministeriums der Justiz für die rechtsförmliche Gestaltung von Gesetzen und Rechtsverordnungen nach § 42 Absatz 4 und § 62 Absatz 2 der Gemeinsamen Geschäftsordnung der Bundesministerien)</sup></sub> findet man den Hinweis, dass es in Fällen, in denen das Geschlecht nicht bekannt oder für den jeweiligen Zusammenhang unwichtig ist, gerechtfertigt sein kann, die grammatisch maskuline Form verallgemeinernd zu verwenden (generisches Maskulinum).

> Beispiel:
>   § 535 des Bürgerlichen Gesetzbuchs:
>   (1)   Durch den Mietvertrag wird *der Vermieter* verpflichtet, *dem Mieter* den Gebrauch der Mietsache während der Mietzeit zu gewähren. *Der Vermieter* hat die Mietsache *dem Mieter* in einem zum vertragsgemäßen Gebrauch geeigneten Zustand zu überlassen und sie während der Mietzeit in diesem Zustand zu erhalten. *Er* hat die auf der Mietsache ruhenden Lasten zu tragen.
>   (2)   *Der Mieter* ist verpflichtet, *dem Vermieter* die vereinbarte Miete zu entrichten.

Comment: Es kann im Deutschen keine objektive Gleichbehandlung geben, weil der generische Begriff (etwa: Mieter) nicht das Geschlecht des Mieters betrifft, sondern nur das Wort ist männlich, wie Hammer. Bei Lebewesen, die ein Geschlecht haben, ist es möglich eine Endung zu verwenden, wenn man exklusiv Frauen o. Weibchen meint. Für Männer o. Männchen gibt es keine vergleichbare Endung und so besteht eine Asymetrie, von der man aber nicht sagen kann dass sie irgendwen benachteiligt. Im Tierreich gibt es auch generische Bez. die fem. sind, etwa Katzen, und daher Katzenfutter; das kann man auch dem Kater..