# Generisches Maskulinum

Tags: formality, salutation

Ich benutze noch immer das generische Maskulinum. Da ich eine Frau bin, nimmt es mir auch keiner übel. Doch überall wo ich lese, erscheint ein anderer Ausdruck und Unterstreichung des Sexus.

In Zeitungen, Wikipedia und akademischen Werken lese ich nur das generische Maskulinum. Wenn ich mir aber Zeitschriften wie die "Emma" oder "Taz" kurz anschaue, sehe ich nur den Binnenmajuskel.

Dann gibt es Universitäten, welche nur das generische Femininum nutzen.

Dann gibt es viele Briefe, die mit "Leserinnen und Leser" oder "Leser/innen" usw. verfasst werden.

Neuerdings werden ganze Gesetze mit "zu Fußgehenden" etc. umgeschrieben.

Meine Fragen:

- darf ich immer noch das generische Maskulinum nutzen?
- wo, wie und wann benutze ich die verschiedenen Geschlechtveranschaulichungen? In jeder Situation eine andere?

Ich habe jetzt so viele verschiedene Methoden gesehen — jeder macht 's, wie er es will. Ich sehe kein System. Hoffentlich könnt ihr mir helfen die einzelnen Methoden aufzulisten und mir erklären, wann man welche nutzt.

Comment: Es gibt schon einige Fragen zu diesem Thema hier: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/18744/ http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2370/ http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/13735/ (englisch) http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/7963/ (englisch) - keine beantwortet aber Deine Frage nach dem System dahinter und wann man das generische Maskulinum nicht verwenden sollte. Vielleicht möchtest Du in Deiner Frage präzisieren, was Dir an den dortigen Antworten fehlt, damit die Leute hier kein Duplikat sehen.

Comment: siehe vielleicht auch diese Antwort: http://german.stackexchange.com/a/22055/9551

Comment: In ihrem jetzigen Zustand ist die Frage ziemlich meinungsbasiert (auch wenn das vielleicht gar nicht beabsichtigt ist), da es keinerlei Kodex diesbezüglich gibt und sich damit alles auf nicht mit Tatsachen untermauerbare Fragen wie diejenige reduziert, ob das generische Maskulinum der Gleichberechtigung abträglich ist oder nicht.

Comment: Liebe Frau Fröhlich, nutzen Sie doch die Deutsche Sprache in der schönen Form, die sie gewohnt sind - insbesondere wenn niemand Sie kritisiert - denn auch als Frau wird man das schon. Sie leisten damit einen Beitrag zur Abkühlung der Gemüter und der Einkehr der Vernunft. Anfangs war es mir ein ernstes Anliegen, niemanden zu kränken. Je mehr ich mich mit diesen Dingen beschäftige, desto mehr verliere ich jede derartige  Hoffnung.

Comment: In die Emma habe ich schon lange nicht mehr geschaut, aber Du scheinst ebenso lange nicht mehr in die taz geschaut zu haben.

Comment: Alles was Ingmar sagt. Ergänzend: Das generische Maskulin bedeutet nicht, dass man die männliche Form über alles drüber stülpt, wie es allerorts behauptet. Sondern es ist genau umgekehrt.
Es gab erst eine allgemeine Form, dann wurde eine explizit weibliche dazu erschaffen. Das bedeutet, dass in der allgemeinen Form die männliche enthalten ist, aber nicht exklusiv. Das passt allerdings nicht ins politische Narrativ. Ansonsten finde ich den Ausdruck nicht schlecht. Allerdings setzt er vorraus, dass man weiß, was *generisch*, *Generikum* bedeutet. Im Prinzip ist es ein Abstraktum, das nur von Sit

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ich halte das Binnen-I für eine ungrammatikalische Abomination. Je nach intendierter Zielgruppe wird man mit dem generischen Maskulinum das Auslangen finden, oder eben beide Geschlechter verwenden müssen.

Weder die *Emma* noch die *taz* sind dabei repräsentative Beispiele.

> Darf ich immer noch das generische Maskulinum nutzen?

Wer will es Dir verbieten?

> Ich habe jetzt so viele verschiedene Methoden gesehen - jeder macht wie er es will.

So ist es.

> Ich sehe kein System.

Es gibt keinen einheitlichen Standard.

Comment: _Wer will es dir verbieten?_ Nun, falls man Texte nicht nur privat verfaßt, sondern für einen Arbeit- oder Auftraggeber, kann der durchaus Vorgaben machen, und das geschieht auch.

Comment: Als Beispiel § 4 Landesgleichstellungsgesetz NRW: _Gesetze und andere Rechtsvorschriften sollen sprachlich der Gleichstellung
von Frauen und Männern Rechnung tragen. Im dienstlichen Schriftverkehr ist auf
die sprachliche Gleichbehandlung von Frauen und Männern zu achten. In
Vordrucken sind geschlechtsneutrale Personenbezeichnungen zu verwenden. Sofern
diese nicht gefunden werden können, sind die weibliche und die männliche
Sprachform zu verwenden._

Comment: Und die genaueren Vorgaben im Rahmen eines Erlasses: https://recht.nrw.de/lmi/owa/br_show_anlage?p_id=958

Comment: Sicher, der Staat kann von seinen Beamten (wie jeder Arbeitgeber von seinen Bediensteten) auch Texte in toten und lebend Fremdsprachen oder ärgers verlangen ... für alle anderen gilt: eine normative Pflicht zu gendern gibt es nicht, und das gilt erst recht fürs Binnen-I (wäre ja noch schöner)

Comment: OT: Und ich dachte immer, "abomination" sei ein englisches Wort, und die deutsche Entsprechung sei "Greul" ... Woerterbuchnetz.de [findet es übrigens nicht](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/startGlobalSearch.tcl?stichwort=+Abomination).

Comment: @chirlu: Das Landesgleichstellungsgesetz von NRW lässt die sprachliche korrekte Form insofern offen, als "Fußgänger" eben die geschlechtsneutrale Form ja gerade _ist_.

Comment: @dirkt: _Abomination_ gehört, wie Du siehst, zu meinem (wenn auch selten gebrauchten) aktiven Wortschatz. Dass eine bestimmte Website es nicht kennt, ändert daran nichts; und bevor jemand behauptet es sei ein Anglizismus, lese er nach bei Bruder Ordinarius https://books.google.at/books?id=zLc8AAAAcAAJ&pg=PA55&lpg=PA55&dq=%22eine+abomination%22&source=bl&ots=6Ic-xxZMiS&sig=3I92s7rSNoJ1-Xk5RmNe2dcyyIM&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0CB4Q6AEwADgKahUKEwiP1bjQxvrGAhXJyRQKHXK_D88#v=onepage&q=%22eine%20abomination%22&f=false Dass es nicht besonders häufig gebraucht wird, will ich dabei gar nicht bestreiten.

Answer (score 8):

> darf ich immer noch das generische Maskulinum nutzen?

Natürlich, außer wenn der (i.d.R. geschriebene und ggf. vorgetragene) Text bestimmten Richtlinien entsprechen muss, die etwa eine Redaktion oder Behörde für Dokumente aus ihrem Haus beschlossen hat (siehe unten).

> wo, wie und wann benutze ich die verschiedenen Geschlechtveranschaulichungen?
> In jeder Situation einen anderen?

Das hängt u.a. von der Textsorte ab. In Formularen oder Tabellen wird man sich bspw. entweder für eine Kurzschreibweise von Beidnennungen entscheiden oder geschlechtsneutrale Formulierungen verwenden. Manchmal ist es sinnvoll verschiedene Varianten zu verwenden, anderswo muss man sich einmal für eine entscheiden und diese durchhalten, was auch einen Einfluss auf die Wahl hat.

### Leitfäden

Es gibt verschiedene Leitfäden oder Richtlinien für einen geschlechter-/gendergerechten/-fairen/-sensiblen Formulieren allgemeiner Sprachgebrauch im Sinne des Gender Mainstreaming, manchmal ergänzt um Regeln und Hinweise zu Illustrationen aller Art oder zu anderen Diskriminierungsgründen (Herkunft, Aussehen, Stand etc.). Fast jede Hochschule (z.B. die [Uni Köln](http://www.gb.uni-koeln.de/gleichstellung_an_der_universitaet/gendersensible_sprache/)) gibt heutzutage einen eigenen heraus, die Unterschiede halten sich in Grenzen. Die meisten sind eher kurz (so 2 bis 8, manchmal rund 20 A4-Seiten) und begründen ihre Empfehlungen nicht oder nur unzureichend, sondern stellen einfach nur diverse Möglichkeiten vor (und lassen nicht bevorzugte weg).

Wirklich umfangreich (190 Seiten), durchdacht und strukturiert (Begründung, Möglichkeiten, Faustregeln, Textsorten, Stichworte) – entsprechend häufig referenziert, aber meistens schlecht abgeschrieben – ist der [Leitfaden der Schweizer Bundeskanzlei](https://www.bk.admin.ch/dokumentation/sprachen/04915/05313/index.html?lang=de). Er entscheidet sich nur etwas zu häufig dafür, Frauen bzw. das Geschlecht unbedingt sichtbar machen zu wollen, wo Konservative und Queerttheoretiker oder LGBT-Bewegte anderer Meinung wären. Der Schweiz- und Verwaltungsfokus ist erträglich.
Für deutsche Bundesbehörden gibt es u.a. das BBB-Merkblatt M19.

Der Ursprung für den deutschen Sprachraum sind die in den Linguistischen Berichten 1980 und 1981 erschienen „Richtlinien zur Vermeidung sexistischen Sprachgebrauchs“ von den Vorreiterinnen des sprachlichen Feminismus in Deutschland, Ingrid Guentherodt, Marlis Hellinger, Luise F. Pusch und Senta Trömel-Plötz.
Klassiker aus den 1990ern stammen von der [UNESCO](http://www.ottobib.com/isbn/3927907324) und vom [Netzwerk schreibender Frauen](http://www.ottobib.com/isbn/3881042245).
Zur Abschreckung aus der ganz linken, queertheoretischen Ecke stammt ein aktuelles Papier aus der [HU Berlin](http://feministisch-sprachhandeln.org).

**Alle** diese Leitfäden lehnen das „generische Maskulinum“ ab (außer evtl. für rein juristische Personen) und bestehen oft fast nur aus Vorschlägen, wie man es ersetzen kann, um entweder auch Frauen explizit zu nennen oder Hinweise aufs Geschlecht ganz zu verstecken. Die besseren Regelwerke fordern, gerade nicht bestehende Texte im Nachhinein „durchzugendern“, sondern sie bereits initial geschlechtsbewusst zu formulieren.

### Vorschläge

Das eigentliche Problem sind aber nicht maskuline Generika (*der Mensch, Gast, Lehrling*) und Pseudogenerika (*der Leser, Kollege, Rektor*), sondern ist, dass es überhaupt feminine Spezifika gibt, die von diesen – insbesondere aber von Nomina Agens auf *+er* mit Verbalstamm – regulär abgeleitet werden (*die Leserin, Kollegin, Rektorin*, sogar *Männin*, jedoch nicht *die *Menschin, *Gästin, *Lehrlingin*), aber keine parallelen maskulinen Spezifika existieren – und natürlich auch keine zu femininen oder neutralen Generika (*die Person, das Kind*).
Nur einige Fremdwörter aus Sprachen mit echtem Differenzialgenus (*Guillero, Guillera; Magister, Magistra*) und Komposita mit partiallexemisch determinierten Geschlecht (*Fachmann, Fachfrau, Fachleute; Tennisdamen, Tennisherren*) sind wirklich **geschlechterparallel** (und damit wiederum *nicht* queerinklusiv).
Diverse Konstrukte sind hingegen **geschlechtsabstrakt**, darunter überwiegend feminine, neutrale oder plurale Derivative und Komposita (*die Putzhilfe, Lehrkraft, Vertrauensperson, das Personal, Publikum, Rektorat, die Stellvertretung, Belegschaft*) sowie eingeschränkt substantivierte Adjektive und Partizipien (*der/die Grüne, Studierende, Abgeordnete* und *-n*, aber *ein Grüner, Studierender, Abgeordneter*).

*Meine* derzeitige allgemeine Empfehlung, die nicht den gängigen feministischen oder queeren Ansprüchen genügt, ist: **vermeide Agentien mit *+er* ebenso wie Movierungen mit dem Suffix *+in(nen)*!**
Die Frage nach der besten Kurzschreibweise (Klammer, Schrägstrich, Binnenmajuskel, Gendergap etc.) von Beidnennungen stellt sich dann bspw. gar nicht. Allerdings erfordert das entsprechende Formulieren etwas Übung, die mir selbst noch fehlt, und die nötige sprachliche Kreativität erzeugt hier und da auch einen Neologismus, der ebenso befremden kann wie der dann sich leicht einschleichende unlebendige, entpersonalsierte Stil. Es hilft allerdings, wenn man die Pronomen *man* (inkl. *jemand, niemand*) und *wer* (inkl. *sein*) nicht verteufelt.

Answer (score 4):

- Im Normalfall benutzt man das generische Maskulinum, weil es sprachlich richtig ist.
- Bei öffentlichen Reden und Ansprachen spricht man aus Höflichkeit beide Geschlechter an ("Liebe Damen und Herren!", "Verehrte Professorinnen und Professoren") und fährt dann wie oben fort.
- Wenn man in einer Bittstellerposition ist und die Seite der Macht eine andere Politik verfolgt, fügt man sich deren Wünschen und Gewohnheiten, wenn es das wert ist.

Comment: "sprachlich richtig" finde ich dünnes Eis, da im 19. Jh die Frauen durch die allein männliche Anrede explizit ausgeschlossen worden seien (https://www.tagesspiegel.de/wissen/streit-um-das-generische-maskulinum-mitgemeint-aber-ausgeschlossen/23077686.html). Der zweite Anstrich: nur aus Höflichkeit in der Anrede die Frauen zu erwähnen und dann mit den Männern fortfahren - naja, konsequent. Es ist nun (2019) bis zum Gesetzgeber durchgedrungen, dass es mehr als zwei Geschlechter geben kann, allein die sprachliche Lösung - darauf bin ich auch gespannt.

Comment: @ShegitBrahm: Kommt auf den Kontext an, in dem man "Geschlecht" verwendet. Fortpflanzungsfähige Geschlechter gibt es beim Menschen und den allermeisten Tieren nur 2. Die Argumentation im TSP ist ja unterirdisch! Es würde die Kommentare sprengen, auf alles einzugehen. Stichworte: MuttER, SchwestER, die ButtER. Die generische Form wird auch nicht nur für Berufe benutzt - Spanier, Diebe, Fußgänger. Da sind Männer genauso MITgemeint wie Frauen. Ohne Kontext ist kein Geschlecht damit gemeint. Wie Männer durch das weibliche Wort Person auch mitgemeint sind, ohne dass es sprachlich schief klingt.

Comment: Mir kommt es nur auf die Feststellung an, dass durch die Verwendung des Maskulinums explizit Frauen ausgeschlossen wurden und damit der "historische Beleg" über "war von Anfang an immer mitgemeint" nach meinem Verständnis keinen Bestand hat. Sonst wäre es m.E. normal, "Sehr geehrte Anwesende/Bürger/..." zu sagen, statt explizit zu den Herren die Damen anzusprechen. Denn die Hinzunahme der Damen machte ihre Existenz sichtbar. Die Art & Zahl der Geschlechter festzulegen ist gleichwohl kontextabhängig und schwierig.

Comment: @ShegitBrahm: Diese Sichtbarkeitsphrase mal beiseite: Eine generische Interpretation von Maskulinformen in rechtlichen Texten hätte man nicht explizit verneint, wenn sie selbstverständlich wäre. Was die Aussage belegen soll widerlegt sie. Der gleiche Versuch durch geheucheltes Missverstehen der Sprache seine politischen Absichten zu begründen, nur in die andere Richtung.

Answer (score 2):

Da es bisher noch in keiner Antwort erwähnt wurde: Das generische Maskulinum eignet sich nicht für eine Gruppe von Frauen bzw. weiblichen Angesprochenen.

Die beste Variante, mit der Kritik am generischen Maskulinum umzugehen, ist meiner Meinung nach: Hin und wieder oder generell das generische Femininum zu nutzen (generell -> eher als Frau). Das zeigt ganz klar auch der priviligierten Gruppe das Problem des generischen Maskulinums auf. "Bin ich jetzt mitgemeint oder nicht?"

Comment: Eine Gruppe weiblicher Studenten kann als durchaus geben. Siehe die Antwort von Toscho in diesem Thread: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/13735/how-do-germans-refer-to-people-without-caring-about-the-gender

Comment: Und das ist weniger problematisch als einfach Studentinnen? Oder richtiger? Wo steht, dass das richtiger wäre?

Comment: Du schreibst, dass das generische Maskulinum sich nicht eignet für eine Gruppe von Frauen bzw. weiblichen Angesprochenen. Das stimmt so aber nicht. Man kann durchaus auch eine Gruppe von weiblichen Studenten mit dem generischen Maskulinum ansprechen. Das ist nicht falsch (Richtiger ist aber auch auch nicht).

Comment: Ich persönlich habe keine Probleme, mich mitgemeint zu fühlen, wenn regelmäßig oder manchmal generische Feminina verwendet werden.

Comment: Das sprachliche Geschlecht ist einfach etwas anderes, als das Geschlechtsmerkmal gemeinter oder möglicherweise gemeinter Individuen. Wer die Polizei ruft, der weiß nicht, ob gerade nur Frauen, nur Männer oder Personen gemischten Geschlechts auf der Wache sind und will es auch nicht wissen. Die Bäckerinnung wird auch nicht umbenannt, wenn ihr nur noch weibliche Bäcker angehören und Du sagst auch "die Person" wenn es ein Mann ist. Die Gendersprache basiert auf einer Verschwörungstheorie und wie ein Hebel, der am falschen Punkt ansetzt, kann sie auch kein Problem lösen.

Comment: Sprache und Sprachwahl hat also keine Auswirkung auf das echte Leben?

Comment: @PythoNic: Kommt drauf an, wie weit Du Sprachwahl ausdehnst. Für alle sprachlichen Phänomene trifft es sicher nicht zu. Aber bei politisch motivierten Euphemismen wie Vorratsdatenspeicherung dauerte es eben eine Zeit, dann hat das Wort doch die negativen Reaktionen ausgelöst, die es vermeiden sollte (Vorräte speichern, Sorge für die Zukunft) und die Politiker versuchten einen neuen Begriff zu etablieren (gerade vergessen).  Auswirkung von Binnen-I und Sternchen sind aber sichtbar: In mündlicher Rede fangen die Verwender an zu stammeln, Äh zu sagen, und kommen vom Thema ab.

Comment: Es bildet sich eine Gruppe, die ihre Ideologie hörbar vor sich herträgt, und die Übung im Gendern gilt als Ausweis der Gruppenzugehörigkeit. Outsider fühlen sich dann rasch abgeschreckt und befassen sich gar nicht erst mit den Texten. Feminismus wird dann als pedantischer Bürokratismus wahrgenommen und zieht auch v.a. bürokratische Pedanten an. Ob das die gewünschte Auswirkung ist, bezweifle ich. Dass gegenderte Stellenanzeigen mehr Frauen anlocken bezweifle ich.

Comment: Es ist schön wie du das umdrehst. Mir ging es darum, dass die Frau viel länger als zu einem Mann zugehörig betrachtet wird und wurde, weil die Sprache hinterherhinkt, aber lassen wir das. Es klingt so, du willst es nicht wahrhaben, dass auch Kritik an der Sprache sinnvoll ist. Wenn du nur die absurden Varianten siehst, dann kannst du das ja nur als Quatsch finden. Dennoch: es gibt ein in der Sprache sichtbares Ungleichgewicht, z.B. >7.600 verschiedene Lehmann und Hermann, http://www.deutsche-nachnamen.de/index.php/namen-mit-endung-mann

Comment: "Outsider fühlen sich dann rasch abgeschreckt und befassen sich gar nicht erst mit den Texten." ?? Die Artikel https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feministische_Linguistik und https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gender_Bias sehen für mich recht lesbar aus. Aber vielleicht hast du recht, mensch muss abgeholt werden, da wo er ist, auch du. Vielleicht kümmert sich ja jemand um dich, damit du dich nicht so abgeschreckt fühlst...