# Geschlechtsneutrale Übersetzung für „cousins“

Tags: english-to-german, gender, spoken-language, gender-neutrality

Ich übersetze einen englischen Text, worin sich die Wörter „my cousins“ im Kontext auf einen Cousin (männlich) und zwei Cousinen (weiblich) bezieht. Die korrekteste Übersetzung wäre also vermutlich „meine Cousinen und mein Cousin“.

Das scheint mir allerdings im Vergleich zum Originaltext ein wenig zu lang/holprig, und es klingt auch nicht nach natürlichem Sprachgebrauch. Gibt es ein deutsches Wort für „Cousins/Cousinen“, das beide Geschlechter umfasst? Oder eine andere raffinierte Formulierung?

Comment: Es scheint kein Wort dafür zu geben, alle Verwandschaftsbeziehungen sind anscheinend im Deutschen gender-explizit. Du mußt also "meine Cousins und Cousinen"  schreiben, was auch wieder blöd ist, da ja nur ein Cousin vorhanden ist.

Comment: Oder du umschreibst es mit "die Kinder meiner Tante/meines Onkels"

Comment: @Ingo Wenn man das aber schon so genau nimmt mit der Übersetzung, wie der OP es offenbar tut, muss man dann aber auch sicherstellen, dass es das selbe Ehepaar Tante/Onkel ist, zu dem alle Cousins und Cousinen gehören. ;)

Comment: @pbx genau, das ist eine zusätzliche Schwierigkeit. "die Kinder der Geschwister meiner Eltern" klingt dann doch doof ....

Comment: @Ingo: _Geschwisterkind_ als Synonym für Cousin bzw. Cousine gibt es tatsächlich, wird aber eher selten gebraucht, wohl auch veraltend.

Comment: @Ingo: Gegenbeispiel: Kind, Enkelkind, Eltern, Großeltern.

Comment: Wieso soll die Formulierung zu lang sein? Was soll daran holprig sein? Holprig wirds, wenn Du aus Krampf was kurzes suchst.

Comment: @userunknown An sich stimme ich zu. Das Problem ist, dass der englische Text diese „cousins“ etwas häufiger erwähnt und dabei jedes Mal alle drei Personen gemeint sind. Immer wieder diese ausführliche Übersetzung zu verwenden wird auf Dauer etwas merkwürdig.

Comment: @Ingmar: *Geschwisterkind* ist aber insbesondere verwirrend, weil es heute auch als Synonym für *Geschwister* (mit Betonung darauf, dass auch das Geschwister ein Kind ist) verwendet wird. Das Wort begegnet einem beispielsweise häufig im Zusammenhang mit Kindertageseinrichtungen.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper:  Huch, ein Homonym! :-)

Comment: @Ingmar Und auch verwirrend, denn *Geschwisterkinder* würde ich erst einmal als *Neffen und Nichten* verstehen, nicht als Vettern und Basen.

Comment: Duden lässt auch diese Leseweise zu, ja.

Comment: @Andii: VIelleicht brauchst Du die Formulierung einmal kurz in Folge, und kannst Dich beim zweiten Mal mit "die drei" auf die drei beziehen, und dann später vermehrt "die drei" schreiben, so dass es die Leser verstehen. Was hätte der Autor geschrieben, wenn er deutsch könnte? *Die anderen Kinder* vielleicht? Ohne den Text zu kennen wissen wir natürlich nicht, ob das zur Abgrenzung reicht. *Susi, Tom und Petra*? Anverwandte holt man aus der Mottenkiste, wenn es ein Begräbnis gibt. Wenn jmd. seine Cousins und Cousinen so nennt würde ich annehmen, dass sie sich ziemlich fremd sind.

Comment: Den Ansatz von @userunknown finde ich ebenfalls gut. Je nachdem, welche Personen in dem Text sonst noch vorkommen, könnte man auch nach der ersten Erwähnung zusammenfassend "meine Verwandten", "meine Familie" o. ä. schreiben.

Comment: Einfach "meine Cousinen und Cousins". Das ist kurz genug und üblich.

Comment: Das gleiche Problem gibt es für “parent”. Es gibt Eltern, aber eine einzelne Person ist Vater oder Mutter (oder Elternteil, oder Erziehungsberechtigte)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Geschwister zweiten Grades* wäre wohl theoretisch (genealogisch) korrekt und geschlechtsneutral, aber völlig ungebräuchlich und damit unverständlich. *Geschwisterkinder* kenne ich nur für die Gesamtheit der Nichten und Neffen, sowie *Schwiegerkinder* nur für Ehepartner der eigenen Kinder, aber **Schwiegergeschwister* könnte man eventuell entsprechend neu prägen.

Wenn der Protagonist selbst keine Geschwister hat, trifft auch die Umschreibung *Verwandte gleicher Generation* oder in vielen Fällen *gleichaltrige Verwandte* eindeutig zu. (Bei mir bspw. funktioniert beides nicht.) Ebenfalls die Brüder und Schwestern mit einbeziehen würden die schön knappen, aber unüblichen *Koenkel* oder *Mitenkel*, da das ausschlaggebende Kriterium das gemeinsame Großelternteil/-paar ist. Entsprechend geht auch *Omas/Opas andere Enkel*.

Wenn der Vetter/Cousin und die beiden Basen/Kusinen/Cousinen drei Geschwister sind und keine weiteren haben, würde ich im Deutschen möglicherweise eine feste Fügung – z.B. aus dem Familien-, Vaters-, Mutter- oder Ortsnamen – bilden, aber dieses Merkmal muss sich vom Protagonisten unterscheiden. Andere Varianten zur Spitznamenbildung funktionieren natürlich auch. Ob das im konkreten Fall bzw. im englischen Setting allgemein funktioniert, weiß ich allerdings nicht. Aus der Luft gegriffene Beispiele:

- *die Müllers*
- *die Meyerkinder*
- *die kleinen Jürgens*
- *die Margotbrut*
- *Klausis Bagaluten*
- *die Kölner*
- *die Hamburger Nachzucht*
- *die Lindenstraßenbande*

PS: Die klassischen deutschen Begriffe *Base* und *Vetter* können/konnten regional (auch) beliebige Verwandte ohne eigene Gradvokabel oder sogar familienähnlich eng Bekannte bezeichnen, *Cousin(e)* m.W. nicht.

Comment: "Cousin(e) m.W. nicht." - vielleicht nicht beliebig, aber ich kenne es durchaus als üblich, mehr oder weniger alle Verwandten in meiner Generation, die nicht meine Geschwister sind, als "Cousin" bzw. "Cousine" zu bezeichnen. Das Verwandtschaftsverhältnis ist immerhin i.A. "irgendwie ähnlich"; es mag sich nicht direkt um ein Kind von Onkel oder Tante handeln, sondern es liegt eben noch eine "Ecke" dazwischen, indem das Kind vom Kind von Großonkel oder Großtante ist, oder das Kind von Onkel oder Tante der eigentlichen Cousins/Cousinen etc.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Ja („2. Grades“ und so), aber nicht für die Onkel/Oheime und Tanten/Muhmen oder Neffen und Nichten.

Comment: Nachdem ich ein paar Tage abgewartet habe akzeptiere ich diese Antwort mal; diese Art der Umschreibung mit den Beispielen bietet sich wirklich sehr gut an. Ich hatte zwar ursprünglich auf ein zusammenfassendes Wort gehofft, aber das scheint es ja nicht zu geben (und selbst wenn wäre es wahrscheinlich sehr ungebräuchlich).

Answer (score -2):

Eine Möglichkeit - so Dir das nicht zu generisch ist - wäre, das Wort

> der/die Anverwandte

zu nutzen, das sich leicht als Sammelbegriff für sowohl Cousin als auch Cousine verwenden lässt und im von dir benötigten Plural mit Possesivpronomen

> meine Anverwandten

für die von Dir genannte Gruppe bestehend aus einem Cousin und zwei Cousinen herhalten kann bei gleichzeitig kurzer Textlänge.

Das zentrale Problem, passende Synonyme zu finden, ist natürlich, dass ohne den Originaltext, den Du übersetzt, keine echte Hilfe möglich ist. Mein o.g. Vorschlag reicht für die meisten Zwecke praktisch aus. Sollte allerdings semantisch wirklich etwas an der exakten Familienbezeichnung hängen, ginge Deinem Text etwas verloren.

**Edit:** Bei näherem Hinsehen sehe ich allerdings das wirkliche zugrundeliegende Problem nicht. Was spricht dagegen - sobald die Personen im Text vorgestellt wurden - den maskulinen Plural zu nutzen mit

> meine Cousins

als Übersetzung für die Gruppierung? *Off-Topic:* Die italienische Sprache zum Beispiel löst das Problem zu langer Anreden genau auf diese Weise. Sobald ein männliches Wesen in einer Gruppierung ist, wird der maskuline Plural verwandt.

Comment: Das Problem ist: Empfindet man das Paar Cousin/Cousine wie Lehrer/Lehrerin oder wie Onkel/Tante?

Comment: @CarstenS Das musst du mir jetzt erklären, ich stehe auf dem Schlauch, was du meinst. Grammatikalisch tendiere ich klar zu ersterem, aber was ändert das im Speziellen an etwaiger Übersetzung?

Comment: @CarstenS eher wie Onkel/Tante, das ist das Problem. Außer "Kinder", "Geschwister" und "Eltern" gibt es anscheinend keine geschlechtsneutralen Verwandschaftsbezeichnungen. Deutlicher wird das noch bei Vetter/Base (was Synonyme für Cousin/Cousine sind)

Comment: Du schreibst, Du sähest das Problem nicht so recht. Aber auch wenn "Lehrer" im Plural Lehrerinnen einschließen kann, so schließt "Onkel" im Plural doch keine Tanten ein. Bei Tanten hat man also ein Problem, und die Frage ist, wie da nun die Cousinen einzuordnen sind.

Comment: @CarstenS Ah, nun sehe ich in der Tat das Problem. Da hast du natürlich Recht. Für mich ist der Wortstamm bei Lehrer(in) respektive Cousin(e) derselbe, wohingegen das bei Onkel/Tante nicht der Fall ist. Insofern bleibe ich bei der Meinung, dass ein simpler Plural für den OP eigentlich genügt.

Comment: Mein Problem mit „Cousins“ ist, dass man dabei im Deutschen spontan wahrscheinlich nur an die männliche Form denkt (wobei es natürlich etwas helfen kann, wenn man den Kontext kennt). Als Notlösung wäre es wohl noch das beste, wobei ich persönlich fast schon eher zu „Cousinen“ tendieren würde, einfach nur weil es davon mehr gibt - aber das schließt natürlich den männlichen Cousin komplett aus.

Comment: Zum ersten Vorschlag sollte man vielleicht noch anmerken, dass (vielleicht je nach Region unterschiedlich? Hier im Südwesten Deutschlands ist es jedenfalls so.) das Wort *Anverwandte* extrem gestelzt klingen kann, im Gegensatz zu dem absolut gebräuchlichen *Verwandte*.

Comment: Ich habe mich eben übrigens noch einmal versichert, dass "cousins" im Französischen generisch verwandt werden kann. Fürs Deutsche sehe ich das nicht so, wahrscheinlich weil die Bildung des Femininums eine französische und keine deutsche ist. Aber andere können das natürlich anders empfinden.

Answer (score -2):

Die natürliche/althergebrachte Übersetzung wäre *meine Cousins* (maskulin Plural).

Erst in den letzten Jahrzenten mit der erzwungenen oder versuchten Genderneutralität wird die Nutzung des maskulin Plurals immer unüblicher. Leider gibt es nicht immer gut klingende Alternativen oder prägnante Formulierungen.
Das endet dann auch vielfach in Wörtern, die es eigentlich nicht gibt: *LehrerIn* (Großbuchstaben mitten im Wort), *Lehrer*in* bzw. *Lehrer/in* (Satzzeichen im Wort). Oder eben sehr lange Formulierungen *Lehrer oder Lehrerin*. Insbesondere bei Stellenausschreibungen findet man dann auch noch den Anhang *(m/w)* für *männlich oder weiblich*.

Comment: Hast Du einen Beleg dafür, dass *Cousins* früher so verwendet wurde?

Comment: Ich schließe mich an. Ich bin zwar jung, aber ein generisch-maskuliner Plural bei *Cousin* ist mir unbekannt. Ich kenne nur *Cousins und Kusinen* – bzw. in älterer Literatur *Vettern und Basen.* Es stellt sich schon die Frage, warum *Cousin* (trotz der deutlich anders klingend *Kusine)* eine Funktion erfüllt haben soll, die andere Wörter *(Onkels* für *Onkels und Tanten?)* nicht hatten.

Comment: Ich will das hier nicht an dem exakten Wort festmachen. Ich habe auch keine Literaturliste wo und wie das benutzt wird oder wurde. Ich habe es vor vielen Jahren so in der Schule gelernt, dass man bei Gruppen mit Mitgliedern beiderlei Geschlechts die maskuline Plural Form benutzt. In Bezug auf Genderneutralität ist es natürlich total verpönt auf diese Art Vertreter eines Geschlecht zu übergehen, aber damit kommen dann die Unsicherheiten, weil es keine vernünftigen und praktikablen Alternativen gibt.

Comment: @Bernd Wilke πφ, die Kritik an deiner Antwort hat nichts mit der Kritik am generischen Maskulinum (hier wird das zum Beispiel diskutiert: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/24641/generisches-maskulinum)